# Carrito de compras no suma 2 veces el mismo producto

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy aprendiendo `js` y encarando un proyecto de carrito de compras, pero me surgió un problema, no logro sumar 2 productos iguales en mi carrito, es como que le doy 1 vez, lo suma en mi tabla pero se vuelve inutilizable ese producto, es decir. lo toco de vuelta y no lo suma ni me tira la alerta de añadido al carrito

Adjunto código.

```
//VARIABLES GLOBALES
let carrito = [];
let productosJSON = [];

$(document).ready(function(){

    //Renderizar Productos DOM
    renderizandoProductos();
    //renderizandoProductos2();
    obtenerJsonProductos();
   

    // DOM AGREGAR TITULO DE LA PAGINA ARRIBA A LA IZK
    let nombrePrincipal = document.getElementById("nombrePrincipal");
    nombrePrincipal.innerHTML = `<p> Las recetas de Mamá </p>` 


    //LLAMO A FUNCION PARA ORDENAR Y SELECCIONAR PRODUCTOS
    $("#miSeleccion option[value='pordefecto']").attr("selected", true);
    $("#miSeleccion").change(function(){
        ordenar();
    });
    
});

//CREANDO PRODUCTOS
function renderizandoProductos(){
for (const producto of productosJSON){
   $(".listaProductos").append(
    `<li class="col-sm-3 list-group-item border">
    <h2 class="textoProducto"> ${producto.nombre}</h2>
   <img class="imagenesProductos" src=${producto.foto} width="250" height="250" >
   <p></p>
   <b class="precioProducto">$ ${producto.precio}</b>
   <button class='btn btn-info botonCarrito' id='btn${producto.id}'>Añadir Al Carrito</button>
   </li>`);
    //Eventos para cada boton
    $(`#btn${producto.id}`).on('click', function() {
        agregarAlCarrito(producto); //mando completo el objeto
    });
}
}


const obtenerJsonProductos = () => {
    //GETJSON
    const URLJSON = "productos.json";
    $.getJSON(URLJSON, function(respuesta, estado) {
        if (estado == "success") {
            productosJSON = respuesta;
            console.log(productosJSON);
            renderizandoProductos();
        }
    });
}



//ORDENAR POR PRECIO Y AZ
function ordenar(){
    let seleccion = $("#miSeleccion").val();
    console.log(seleccion);
    if (seleccion =="menor"){
    productosJSON.sort(function(a, b){return a.precio - b.precio});
    }else if (seleccion == "mayor"){
        productosJSON.sort(function(a, b){return b.precio- a.precio});
    }else if (seleccion == "alfabetico"){
       productosJSON.sort(function(a, b){
            return a.nombre.localeCompare(b.nombre);
        });
    }
    $("li").remove();
    renderizandoProductos();
}


//CLASE CONSTRUCTORA PRODUCTO DEL CARRITO
class productoCarrito{
    constructor(obj){
        this.id = obj.id;
        this.foto = obj.foto
        this.nombre = obj.nombre;
        this.precio = obj.precio;
        this.cantidad = 1;

    }
}
//AGREGAR AL CARRITO PRODUCTOS
function agregarAlCarrito(productoNuevo) {
    let encontrado = carrito.find(prod => prod.id == productoNuevo.id);
    if (encontrado == undefined){
        let productoaAgregar = new productoCarrito(productoNuevo);
   
    carrito.push(productoNuevo);
    console.log(carrito);
    Swal.fire(
        'Nuevo producto agregado al carrito',
        productoNuevo.nombre,
        'success'
    );
    $("#tablabody").append(
        `<tr>
        <td>${productoaAgregar.id}</td>
        <td>${productoaAgregar.nombre}</td>
        <td id='${productoaAgregar.id}'>${productoaAgregar.cantidad}</td>
        <td>${productoaAgregar.precio}</td>
        </tr>`);

        } else{
            let posicion = carrito.findIndex( p => p.id == productoNuevo.id);
            //console.log
            carrito[posicion].cantidad += 1;
            $(`#${productoNuevo.id}`).html(carrito[posicion].cantidad);
            console.log(carrito);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error está en `if(encontrado == undefined)` que, en todo caso, deberías usar [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), quedando la comparación así:

```
if(typeof encontrado == 'undefined')
```

Revisa la consola del navegador para ver los mensajes de error. Ejemplo:

```js
// Así es como se debe comparar
if(typeof noDefinido == 'undefined') {
    console.log('Comparación correcta');
}
// Esto va a generar un error
if(noDefinido == undefined) {
    console.log('No definido');
}
```

Pero puedes simplificar la lógica si solo buscas una vez la posición del producto en el carrito, directamente con `.findIndex()`, que devuelve la posición o `-1` si no existe.

Finalmente, los ID en HTML no deben ser solo números, aunque puede funcionar, lo adecuado es que comience con letra y, para mejor entendimiento del código, usa `prod-{idDelProducto}`:

```
// Agregar productos al carrito
function agregarAlCarrito(productoNuevo) {
    // Busca directamente la posición, no necesitas el elemento
    let posicion = carrito.findIndex(prod => prod.id == productoNuevo.id);
    if (posicion == -1) {
        // El producto no está en el carrito
        let productoaAgregar = new productoCarrito(productoNuevo);
        carrito.push(productoNuevo);
        // El ID no debe ser numérico
        $("#tablabody").append(
            `<tr id="tr-">
            <td>${productoaAgregar.id}</td>
            <td>${productoaAgregar.nombre}</td>
            <td id="prod-${productoaAgregar.id}">${productoaAgregar.cantidad}</td>
            <td>${productoaAgregar.precio}</td>
        </tr>`);
        Swal.fire(
            'Nuevo producto agregado al carrito',
            productoNuevo.nombre,
            'success'
        );
    } else {
        // El producto existe, actualizar cantidad y HTML
        carrito[posicion].cantidad += 1;
        $(`#prod-${productoNuevo.id}`).html(carrito[posicion].cantidad);
    }
}
```